# Remove Rows that Contain a specific Value anywhere in the row (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all rows in a Panda dataset that contain the symbol "+" anywhere in the row.  So ideally this:

```
  Keyword   
  +John
  Mary+Jim
  David
```

would become

```
  Keyword
  David
```

I've tried doing something like this in my code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
excluded = ('+')
removal2 = removal[~removal['Keyword'].isin(excluded)]
```

The problem is that sometimes the + is contained within a word, at the beginning of a word, or at the end.  Any ideas how to help?  Do I need to use an index function?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the vectorised `str` method `contains` and pass the '+' identifier, negate the boolean condition by using `~`:

```
In [29]:

df[~df.Keyword.str.contains('\+')]
Out[29]:
  Keyword
2   David
```