# remove all rows in pandas dataframe with mixed data types that contain a specific string in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I remove all rows in a dataframe if a row contains '9999-Don't Know' in any column?

I have been able to find solutions that delete rows based on format of value (string, numerical, etc.) in the entire dataframe, or delete rows based on values in a specific column, or delete rows from a dataframe that has few columns by using their names.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554078/remove-rows-that-contain-a-specific-value-anywhere-in-the-row-pandas-python-3) is the closest thing I found but this solution doesn't work for me because I cannot enter all the column names due to sheer volume (76+ columns).

Below is a sample dataset

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items([('RespondentId', ['1ghi3g','335hduu','4vlsiu4','5nnvkkt','634deds','7kjng']), ('Satisfaction - Timing', ['9-Excellent','9-Excellent','9999-Don\'t Know','8-Very Good','1-Very Unsatisfied','9999-Don\'t Know']),('Response Speed - Time',['9999-Don\'t Know','9999-Don\'t Know','9-Excellent','9-Excellent','9-Excellent','9-Excellent'])])
```

After removing the 4 rows that contain '9999-Don't Know', the output should look like this so I can write a new Excel file with the cleaned up data.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items([('RespondentId', ['5nnvkkt','634deds']), ('Satisfaction - Timing', ['8-Very Good','1-Very Unsatisfied']),('Response Speed - Time',['9-Excellent','9-Excellent'])])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
In [677]: df[~(df == "9999-Don't Know").any(axis=1)]
Out[677]:
  RespondentId Satisfaction - Timing Response Speed - Time
3      5nnvkkt           8-Very Good           9-Excellent
4      634deds    1-Very Unsatisfied           9-Excellent
```

Or

```
In [683]: df[(df != "9999-Don't Know").all(axis=1)]
Out[683]:
  RespondentId Satisfaction - Timing Response Speed - Time
3      5nnvkkt           8-Very Good           9-Excellent
4      634deds    1-Very Unsatisfied           9-Excellent
```

Same as

```
In [686]: df[~df.eq("9999-Don't Know").any(axis=1)]
Out[686]:
  RespondentId Satisfaction - Timing Response Speed - Time
3      5nnvkkt           8-Very Good           9-Excellent
4      634deds    1-Very Unsatisfied           9-Excellent
```

Or

```
In [687]: df[df.ne("9999-Don't Know").all(axis=1)]
Out[687]:
  RespondentId Satisfaction - Timing Response Speed - Time
3      5nnvkkt           8-Very Good           9-Excellent
4      634deds    1-Very Unsatisfied           9-Excellent
```

---

With mixed column types, see @PiR's comment `df.astype(object)`

```
In [695]: df[df.astype(object).ne("9999-Don't Know").all(axis=1)]
Out[695]:
  RespondentId Satisfaction - Timing Response Speed - Time
3      5nnvkkt           8-Very Good           9-Excellent
4      634deds    1-Very Unsatisfied           9-Excellent
```

Comment: In the event that you have mixed `dtype`... use `df.astype(object).ne("9999-Don't Know").all(axis=1)`

Comment: @John Galt. Thanks for the solution but it didn't work. I got the TypeError: Could not compare ["9999-Don't Know"] with block values. I got the same error when I was trying to count the number of rows that had this string. That whole question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220656/counting-total-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-with-the-same-string-value-in-multiple-c)

Comment: I was trying the solution with replace but this is very fast. +1

Comment: maybe in replace add `regex`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see this earlier question, like @piRSquared mentions, convert the `dtype` with `df.astype(object)..` and then hit it!

Comment: @JohnGalt so the script definitely worked. However, I have a doubt because when I counted rows with that string using `df.astype(str).eq("9999-Don't Know").values.sum()`, I got 72111. When I run `df[df.astype(object).ne("9999-Don't Know").all(axis=1)]` to remove rows with that string, only ~54k rows are removed. It's possible that the code I'm using to count the rows is not correct but I don't know how to verify.

Comment: So I WAS able to verify it manually using Excel and turns out that the snippet you gave me to remove the rows with that string IS accurate. Thanks!